# Find current domain URL for universal script PHP

Tags: php, css, url, path

You can do this?

```
background-color: url(".<?php current domain ?>."/shop/img/test.jpg");
```

i want the current url to create universal scripts for my site

Comment: Yes, you can get the domain / URL, look into the GLOBALS ( `$_SERVER` )

Comment: Try `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

or

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

or

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
```

[PHP $_SERVER - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)